# Accessing current ClientDetails inside custom UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I'm using **Spring Boot OAuth Authorization Server** (*old stack*) and implementing my own versions of `ClientDetailsService` and `UserDetailsService`, using Oauth2 `password` flow.

Our `JpaClientDetailsService` implements `loadClientByClientId` and returns a `ClientDetails`, with the details of the client that is being authenticated.

```
@Service
public class JpaClientDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService {

    @Override
    public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId) throws ClientRegistrationException {
    
        BaseClientDetails baseClientDetails = new BaseClientDetails(...);

        //do processing....

        return baseClientDetails;

    }

}
```

After that, the method `loadUserByUsername` of our implementation of `JpaUserDetailsService` is called, receiving the username of user that is trying to authenticate:

```
@Service
public class JpaUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        return null;

    }

}
```

My question is:
How could I access the current `ClientDetails`, returned by `JpaClientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId` inside `JpaUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I realized that `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` contains information about the `client` that is being authenticated. So, I was able to get the `client`'s name and load it's data as follow:

```
@Service
public class JpaUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private OAuthClientsRepository oAuthClientsRepository;

    @Override
    public org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        //Gets the Authentication from SecurityContextHolder
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        
        //ClientId is 'Principal's' Username
        var clientId = ((User) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername();

        //Gets clientDetails from JPA Repository. This would execute another Roundtrip to Database, but since we have 2nd level cache configured, this
        //problema is minimized.
        ClientDetails authClient = oAuthClientsRepository
                .findByClientId(clientId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchClientException(String.format("ClientId '%s' not found", clientId)));

        //....

    }

}
```

That's it.